# Интернет вдали от "цивилизации"

Tags: сеть, провайдер

Вопрос не совсем привычный для данного сайта, но более удачного места найти не могу.

Есть необходимость провести интернет в отдаленное место для серверов и биткоин-фермы, само место находится вдали от населенных пунктов, соответственно про оптоволоконный интернет речи быть не может, как и про "простые провода".

Рассматриваю вариант со спутниковым интернетом, но его скорость довольно мала, для нужных задач необходима линия минимум 100 мб/с.

Хотел узнать у людей, которые сталкивались с подобной проблемой, либо как-то связаны с похожей темой - какие есть варианты, какая средняя скорость спутникового интернета?

Comment: Сотовой связи тоже нет? :-) Вообще-то спутниковый интернет он запрос получает по наземной линии и только контент падает со спутника. Ну и на крайний случай нам Господь дал Иридиум.

Comment: Спутниковый интернет явно проигрывает в скорости. Если никак не провести оптоволокно, то можно проверить территорию на наличие поблизости LTE вышек. Но опять таки всё это не надёжно. Всё будет зависеть не только от погодных условий, но и могут возникать постоянные перебои.

Comment: Сигнал wi-fi можно передавать на большие расстояния при помощи промежуточных повторителей. Но тут придется заморочиться, и от расстояния зависит

Comment: Стоит пройти по крупным операторам (Ростелеком, МТС и пр.) на предмет информации о возможности подключения. Можно сделать запрос и они выдают информацию где какие ближайшие точки. Собственно у вас может быть не полная информация о состоянии линии связи.

Comment: Если расстояние не большое то, можно тарелками передать сигнал от ближайшей точки, вот посмотрите [этут статью](https://lantorg.com/article/wifi-antenny-na-2-5-10-15-km-i-bolee)

Answer (score 0):

Договориться с оператором и установить вышку рядом с домом.
Провести интернет оптоволокном.
Спутниковый интернет обеспечит тебе максимум 10-40 мб. сек максимально., так что вариант отпадает.

Comment: Ага, удачи. В одном случае для прокладки километра оптики понадобилось полтора года переговоров и 100 (сто!) предварительно заключённых (своими силами) абонентских договоров. В другом случае, где нужна была установка одной вышки в пределах видимости, все операторы и радио-провайдеры послали нахер, кроме одного, затребовавшего несколько миллионов рублей.

Comment: Про что и речь. Компании нет смысла тратить деньги ради одного человека, вести более сотни километров оптики за свой счет влетит в компеечку и не окупит сервера и биткоин-фермы, исключение огромные фермы.